# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal

I know there are lots of discussion regarding this error but sorry to say that I'm unable to find any working solution over there.

I'm developing a ecommerce site using [ShareTribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe).I'm trying to implement Paypal as payment gateway.So I'm using [Activemerchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant).

Everything works fine on development machine but when I deploy my rails app to production It throws

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)

I'm initializing my Activemerchant as

```
 config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    paypal_options = {
        login: "bla bla",
        password: "bla bla",
        signature: "bla bla",
        appid: "APP-80W284485P519543T"
    }
    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)

  end
```

I'm trying to add Paypal Pem certificates on production but don't have any idea how to link this file with Activemerchant.Any Appreciation will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Create a file active_merchant.rb in initializers & put the below code:

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
    :login => "bla-bla",
    :password => "bla-bla",
    :signature => "bla-bla"
)

Answer (score 1):

SSLv3 was proven to be insecure with the POODLE vulnerability. You should make sure that your system has the latest version of OpenSSL so that you can use TLSv1.2.