# How to enable TLS 1.2 in Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, paypal, centos

I got stucked with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168251/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c) and finally knew

> "SSLv3 was proven to be insecure with the POODLE vulnerability. You
>   should make sure that your system has the latest version of OpenSSL so
>   that you can use TLSv1.2."

I found exact same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319192/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-nginx) but can't find working solution. So how do I enable TLSV1.2 on my cent OS production server?
I'm using ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 3.2.21.

I tried adding `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;` on my nginx configuration file as

```
server {
    listen       80;
        server_name kickmarket.eu www.kickmarket.eu;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /home/kickmarketeu/current/public;
        rails_env production;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

but it didn't worked for me.

```
 root@186-aven-vps nginx]# openssl s_client -connect xx.xx.xx.xx:80 -ssl3
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    140503487715232:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:339:
    ---
    no peer certificate available
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
    ---
    New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
    Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : SSLv3
        Cipher    : 0000
        Session-ID:
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Master-Key:
        Key-Arg   : None
        Krb5 Principal: None
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        Start Time: 1445843616
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    ---
```

I am using the following version of nginx and openssl library.

```
[root@186-aven-vps nginx]# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
[root@186-aven-vps nginx]#  openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Jun 29 12:45:07 UTC 2015
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

Comment: This is not an error. The only sure way to defeat POODLE is to disable SSLv3, which you did. (It doesn't matter if you also enabled TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, although that is a good idea on its own.) If you disable SSLv3 and tell `s_client` to make only an SSLv3 connection, it should fail exactly as it does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot. One thing that I get confused is Do I need to use HTTPs/SSL in order to call Paypal sandbox API?

Answer (score 3):

To make a call to the PayPal Sandbox with TLSv1.2 in Ruby, just make sure that you have OpenSSLv1.0.1c or later (which it looks like you do) and connect to the https API (There is no HTTP equivalent).

You should only need to worry about Nginx config to *receive* TLSv1.2 connections. (Which you probably want to do anyway.) [SSLLabs has a test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) you can use to verify your server's config.